# when I reload a iframe, jquery events are lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am developing an HTML editor, and the editor makes changes on a iframe a complete website,

I have a function `reload` that recharges the iframe reload after saving changes DOM, the problem that all events as click, mouseover are lost ...

I put a portion of code as I'm done.

Load document and iframe:

```
$(document).on("ready",function() {    
   App.init();
});

$('iframe#myiframe').on("load",function(){

  App.frame(); 
  EditIframe.init();   
});
```

App Method

```
var App = function(){

    var iframe    = $("iframe#myiframe").contents();
    var newreload =false;

        var reload= function(){
        $("#reload").on("click",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            App.reset();
            App.init();
            EditIframe.init();
            return;
         });

    };

return{

        init: function () {
            sidebar();
            reload();
            widget();           
        },
        frame:function(){
            editHtml();
            removeHtml();
            addHtml();
            this.hideloading();   
        },
        reset:function(){
            $(".frameWrapper .loading").show();
            document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
        },
        hideloading:function(){
            $(".frameWrapper .loading").hide();
        },
        preparedIframe:function(){
           $(".frameWrapper .loading").find("p.one").after("<p class='two'>Preparing html..</p>");
        },

    };

}();
```

EditIframe Method

```
var EditIframe=function(){

    var iframe    = $("#myiframe").contents();

    var hoverElement=function(){

        iframe.find("*").not("html,body").on("mouseover.selectElementBorder",function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var el = $(this);
            EditIframe.showLine(el);
        }).on('mouseout', function(e) {
             e.stopPropagation();
             var el=$(this);
             EditIframe.hideLine(el);
        });

    };

    return {

        init: function(){
            hoverElement();
        },
        activate:function(){

            this.init();
        },
        deactivate:function(){

            iframe.find("*").off("click mouseout mouseover");
        },
        showLine: function(el){

            el.css({'outline': '3px dashed #2c3e50', 'outline-offset': '-3px', 'cursor': 'pointer'});

        },

    };

}();
```

Well, all is well until the iframe loaded with the function
`App.reset` that the `elementHover` event back not work more.

Is there any solution?

Comment: When you reload a page, everything from the previous contents of the window or iframe is lost. You need to re-run all the Javascript that initializes event handlers.

Comment: It is what I do, or I think, look  App.reset function, add EditIframe.Activate ()  to re-launch the function elementHover

Comment: @Barmar Please can you help. thanks